# Device for PV <UUID> not found

Tags: virtualization, disk, kvm-virtualization, lvm, fdisk

This is how it looks the drive settings of a VM that I am trying to rescue.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                                11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
vda                               252:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─vda1                            252:1    0    1M  0 part
├─vda2                            252:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                            252:3    0   99G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv         253:1    0  199G  0 lvm  /
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv-missing_1_0 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm
└─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv           253:1    0  199G  0 lvm  /

$ sudo pvdisplay -m
  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 213666168832: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 213666226176: Input/output error
  WARNING: Device for PV lm1rJY-LRuU-jpPH-rHeS-4u1u-kRP3-Su9tuH not found or rejected by a filter.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vda3
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <99.00 GiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25343
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          25343
  PV UUID               ItQIGk-0hzo-clpv-e0ZA-Cp8M-uoXO-c0W4G4

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 25342:
    Logical volume  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
    Logical extents 0 to 25342

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               [unknown]
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               100.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25599
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          25599
  PV UUID               lm1rJY-LRuU-jpPH-rHeS-4u1u-kRP3-Su9tuH

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 25598:
    Logical volume  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
    Logical extents 25343 to 50941
```

Interestingly df is showing like everything is kinda ok:

```
$ df -hT
Filesystem                        Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                              devtmpfs  5.7G     0  5.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             tmpfs     1.2G  876K  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4      196G   45G  143G  24% /
tmpfs                             tmpfs     5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                             tmpfs     5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2                         ext4      976M  146M  764M  16% /boot
tmpfs                             tmpfs     1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

But it is obviously not:

```
$ sudo pvscan --cache
  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 213666168832: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 213666226176: Input/output error
```

This was risky but I tried to remove missing volume. But even with --force, it didn't work and I really don't know how to recover this VM. Any help is appreciated.

```
$ sudo lvm
  lvm> vgreduce --removemissing --force ubuntu-vg
      WARNING: Device for PV lm1rJY-LRuU-jpPH-rHeS-4u1u-kRP3-Su9tuH not found or rejected by a filter.
      WARNING: Removing partial LV ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv.
      Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv contains a filesystem in use.
```